# What substance to use for removal of leaked NiMH electrolyte from PCB

Tags: pcb, repair

I have experienced some problems with alarm siren (intermittently alarm goes off) in my car (Audi A3).
After removal of siren and opening its box there are visible marks of corrosion and residues from leaked NiMH battery.

[image: Corrosion]
I attempt to repair the siren. I will fit a new, fresh battery, but the corrosion residues is some of my concern. There is a chance it will continue to react with components/PCB. 
I have desoldered the battery, but removal of the corrosion product is problematic. I have used mid-hard plastic brush and IPA as well as Electrolube LFFR ([Lead-Free Flux Remover](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/products/0283252))
None of above had removed the electrolyte/corrosion product from the PCB completely. There is still some gunk left next to the components or between pins of IC where brush doesn't reach.
What is more adequate product for NiMH electrolyte spillage removal?
Or shall I desolder all affected components and clear whole area?

Comment: Have you googled?  NiMH battery electrolytic is potassium hydroxide, but you've gone after it with non-polar solvents.  If I couldn't find specific recommendations on the web I'd try distilled water followed by a bake-out at 150 F (**not Centigrade** -- convert if you have to) to dry it off.  Then inspect for corrosion.  I'd also be ready to write off the board.

Comment: You'll want to remove that TLE4278G at least. Corrosion likes to get under stuff and do hidden damage. I usually clean with degreaser, blow or bake dry, followed by topical lacquer thinner and/or isopropyl alcohol. Water-based degreaser dilutes and removes the potassium hydroxide. Expect trace damage.

Comment: As Tim saus - water is a surprisingly good solvent BUT the battery MUST be removed first and there MUST be no power on the board. Clean with water (distilled if your tap water is suspect) and a stiff brush. (Don't overdo it, but the components shown should withstand reasonably vigorous brushing). THEN dry very well. | A rdtsc says - corrosion gets in anywhere there is a gap. You MAY be able to insert a plastic sliver under the IC while wet BUT removal is more sure.